# Equivalence of static methods in Go

Tags: go, static-methods

Let's say in Java, I have class *CryptoFormat*, which has a static method named *getLegacyFormat()*. When I want to use the method, I just need to call *CryptoFormat.getLegacyFormat()*. This is clear because I know where the method comes from.

In Go, there is no static method. I don't really want to just make a file called *crypto_format.go* and define the method there. The reason is that whenever I need the method, I just call *GetLegacyFormat()*, which doesn't contain the context where the method comes from.

I could think of two ways to solve the problem:

1. Make a separate package named *cryptoformat*, and define the method as a global function in the package. This way, I need to make a new package for just few methods. Also, whenever I need static methods like this, I have to define new packages.
2. Define a struct named *cryptoFormat* containing method *GetLegacyFormat()*. Also, define a <s>global</s> public variable named *CryptoFormat*, which points to an instance of struct *cryptoFormat*. This way, I can call CryptoFormat.GetLegacyFormat() when I need the method.

I am not sure which one is better, or whether there is better way.

Comment: In the absence of a selector expression, the called function is either a function variable in scope or a function in the current package. Usually, that's sufficient context.   Note that Go does not have global functions or variables.

Comment: You're right. I edited the question.

Comment: Knowing that the called function is either a function variable in scope or in the current package might be ok in a small package. When the package grows, I think a specific context is necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would say option 1 you mention is the more idiomatic way to define such functions, if they don't need any state that would warrant to tie them to an underlying struct.

If there is some state you'd like to have as context for the function, then option 2 would be the way to go.

Note that in Go, functions are "first class citizens", so you don't have Java's constraints of needing to define a class for static methods.

And yes, if you want a separate namespace you'd need to define separate packages (just as in Java you'd need to define separate classes and/or packages).

If you want your implementation to be idiomatic, I'd suggest you take a look at Go's standard libraries (pick a few packages and explore how they implement their functions) to get a better feeling of the usual ways to structure this.

Comment: With option 1, I would have several sub-packages in my package and these packages would contain only one file. Is that common with Go?

Comment: You would typically try to group functions and types related to the same functionality and put them in the same package, so that you don't end up with just one function per package. If they are really simple and unrelated, each package can end up being small, I don't think that'd be unusual either.

Answer (score 6):

> whenever I need the method, I just call GetLegacyFormat(), which doesn't contain the context where the method comes from.

So add context to the function name.

```
GetLegacyCryptoFormat()
```

Comment: And while you're at it, you could probably drop the `Get` off the front.

Answer (score 0):

You can call regular methods like a static one using this syntax (without type instantiation!).

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyClass struct{}

func (m *MyClass) SetValue(value int) {
    fmt.Println(m, value)
}

func main() {
    (*MyClass).SetValue(nil, 123)
}
```